# can't have multiple login screen

Tags: 22.04, login-screen, ubuntu-mate, xdmcp

I am trying to use Ubuntu 22.04 on a PC and multiple X terminal (vcxsrv on window)

XDMCP and X-11 works but i can't have multiple greeter running at the same time :

- Until i login on the server screen, no vcxsrv get any login screen
- After i login on the serser main screen, one vcxsrv got a login screen

Currently using ubuntu mate 22.04 with arctica greeter, but i can switch on any other flavor

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/5-xdmcp.conf :

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver_allow-tcp=true
{XDMCPServer]
enable=true
```